# Error Node downgrading

Tags: node.js, windows, downgrade

I am a beginner in development, but I want to become a leading developer of mobile applications ;)

I am on Windows 8. I want to install Cordova but I have to downgrade Node I currently 0.12.x. Version I could see that he had to make a downgrade in 0.10.x. Version

I do a downgrading but when I want to install an earlier version (0.10.32 and others)

```
npm unistall n
npm install n@0.10.32
```

I have the following errors:

```
C:\Users\Jeremy>npm install n@0.10.32
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (
x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "n@0.10.32"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3

npm ERR! version not found: n@0.10.32
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jeremy\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Node version manager is your friend https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: For windows, [see](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).

Answer (score 0):

if your workflow does not involve global npm installs, etc, one approach is to simply use the `node.exe` executable as a stand-alone -- just grab the version you need from [nodejs.org/dist](https://nodejs.org/dist/) and drop it into the working directory for a particular project. (Node.exe can run without actually 'installing' anything onto the system.)

then you could then specify the version of packages that you need for that version of `node.exe` like so: `npm install foo@0.1.1`.